# Which dimensions for a SplashScreen Picture?

Tags: javascript, java, android, image, android-studio

which dimensions for a splash screen picture and for an backhround picture (? px × ? px) in Android Studio?

Best Regards,
Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on which handset you are targeting. Best bet would be taking 1920x1080 dimension photo as your splash screen background.